# The crashlytics dashboard not appearing? or crashlytics not been enable?

Tags: java, android, firebase, build.gradle, crashlytics

I added crashlytics in my android app following the steps in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android&authuser=3#add-sdk)
when I go to the page of crashlytics in firebase console, the page still appears like this
[image]

I don’t know whats next ? I configured things in my app and run it, and make some crashes and still the page is like this.
I tried to uninstall and install the app and refreshed the page

so maybe I did the configuration wrong
here is my build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.myappandroid"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

android {

    testOptions.unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.cesards.android:cropimageview:1.0.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.8.4'
implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.0.7'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

api 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.1'

///here I add the crashlytics
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'

implementation 'com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation:chip-navigation-bar:1.3.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.70'

}
```

and this is my build.gradle (myappandroid)

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    }

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'

    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
//  classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

please tell me what I am doing wrong or what I missed ? thanks in advance

Comment: Did you build, run and crash your app? Did you actually crash it?

Comment: You should write a line of code that intentionally crashes the app (without trying to catch it or handle it), and then it will appear on your Crashlytics dashboard

Comment: @baselsader yes it crash because I have a place for crash , but didnt write line of code intentionally crash the app I will try that

Comment: @luk2302 yes but I tried my way to crash it without writing code for crash it

Comment: @baselsader Thanks very much, I tried that and it worked